# Compressiopn using GZIPOutputStream and decompression in php

Tags: java, php, compression

I have been communicating with my Java application using php by creating a socket, from Java end, I will compress the result and write those bytes to the php.

```
public static byte[] compressString(byte[] b) throws IOException{
        byte[] compressedBytes = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(b.length);
        try{
            GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
            gzip.write(b, 0, b.length);
            gzip.finish();
            gzip.flush();
            gzip.close();
            compressedBytes = out.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("comp1::"+compressedBytes+", length::"+compressedBytes.length);
        }finally{
            out.close();
        }
        return compressedBytes;
    }
```

But when i am performing

```
$data = fgets($fp);
$decompData = gzuncompress($data);
```

$decompData is returned null.

Kindly provide a solution as i have tried Deflater with gzuncompress, gzdecode and every possible option. There must be something i am missing here. Consider me as newbie in php.

Comment: Have you saved the stream as a file and tried to open it with a zip program to see if the content of the file is ok?

Comment: I have stored everything on the socket in the form of bytes and later using fsockopen() i have found my socket handler and with the help of fread() i am reading bytes without saving to the file or making zip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `gzdecode()` for gzip streams, and you may need to open the file using `"rb"` to read binary data without translation.